# The sum of infinite sum of modified Bessel function

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, bessel-functions

I would like to ask a question about the following problem：

$T(r,z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[C_{1n}I_0(\lambda_nr)+C_{2n}K_0(\lambda_nr)]cos(\lambda_nz)$

in which, $C_{1n}$ and $C_{2n}$ are coefficients, $I_0$, $K_0$ are zero order modified Bessel function, $\lambda_n=\frac{n\pi}{l}$, where $l$ is a constant. Moreover, $r_1<r<r_2$ and $0<z<l$.

The above equation also yields the boundary conditions: $T(r_1,z)=T_1$ and $T(r_2,z)=T_2$.

Actually the $T(r,z)$ is a general solution of a hollow cylinder thermal conduction problem under cylindrical co-ordinate.

I would like to know whether the above mentioned problem have a "closed form expression", which would be similar to "Fourier-Bessel function". I need to determine the coefficients $C_{1n}$ and $C_{2n}$ and obtain the solution of partial differential equation.

Comment: The series diverges because $\lambda_n \to \infty$ thus $I_0( \lambda_n r) \to \infty$. Also, you could have simply edited your previous question instead of asking a new one

Comment: Unless, $\frac{1}{C_{1n}}$ grows faster than  $I_0( \lambda_n r_2)$? Then I suppose the series could converge...

Comment: Let me put it this way: there's no closed form for this series, even if it converges, unless you choose some very special coefficients

Comment: Thanks for your help @YuriyS, This boundary problem could be solved by using the Sturm-Liouville Theorem. Anyway, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you give a link to that thesis you mentioned? I'd like to see how they used this series

Comment: No Problem, please see the following link:https://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/M257_316_2012_Lecture_28.pdf

Comment: I mean with the Bessel functions